# Sharepoint form employee leave calculation form

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, infopath

I would like to create a share point leave request form. which capture employe_name, Line_manager,Dept,leave_opening_balance,Leave_remaining_balance,Leave_days. 
records are saved under a list call "wellbeing leave" I have also created a work flow which will do the calculation to update the column Leave_remaining_balance".

I have created another list called "Wellbeing Leave total" which has 3 column "emp_name,Line_manager,Balance"
I want to create a workflow which will populate/insert record into list"wellbeing leave total" when an item is created in "Wellbeing leave" list. how can i achieve it? any help would be much appriciated

Comment: If you think my reply answers your question and it is what you want, please accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a workflow for the "wellbeing leave" list. Start the workflow automatically when an item is created.

Use "Create List Item" action to create an item in "Wellbeing Leave total" list. And set field values.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Thats what i want to achieve. Much appriciated your help.